# Объединение меток, связанных с [зависимостями]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть такие три метки:

- [dependency](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependency) (1 вопрос)
- [dependencies](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependencies) (63 вопроса)
- [зависимости](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8) (49 вопросов)

Надо их синонимизировать/объединить.